# Do strange parts apply retroactively?

Tags: team-fortress-2

For example, let's say I have a Strange Scattergun with no parts attached and no kills.

I kill 5 medics, then apply a 'Medics Killed' part to the Strange Scattergun.

Then, I kill 5 more medics.

What stat will be displayed? 5 medic kills, or 10 medic kills?

Or another way of phrasing it - will strange parts reflect statistics you accrued before applying the part? Or does it only start counting those statistics after it's been applied?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is a simple **NO**. Strange parts only begin to count the statistics after they are applied. Previous stats are not accounted for.

> When applied, it will not count any previous stats.

Reference: [TF2 Wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange_Part)

Comment: Thanks. Typical that I overlooked the one sentence I was looking for in the entire article :P

Comment: It should also be noted that all counters reset if the item is traded.

Comment: @AustinMohr He did not ask the question. Such answer should be left for other questions. If you want to share such information you can always create and answer your own question to share knowledge in a Q&A form